# Nginx Proxy Manager and php Configuration

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu, nginx

I earlier on installed nginx and was using it to run all php applications including phpmyadmin. When I needed to run some nodejs applications, setting up reverse proxy became an issue. So I found a solution Nginx Proxy Manager. However, I notice that NPM cannot run at the same time with nginx. So that means I can't run my normal php applications.

What could be a way of integrating or using Nginx Proxy Manager with php applications?

I expected that I would simply find a way of having sites-enabled in nginx proxy manager. But this does not exist. I find it easy to use Nginx Proxy Manager for application that run on specific ports.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a static site with the advanced tab.
And add a Docker entry for launching a php-fpm.

I haven't tested that myself. But look at this [comment in an NPM issue](https://github.com/NginxProxyManager/nginx-proxy-manager/issues/58#issuecomment-822000582)

Copied from the comment :

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'

    #...

    links:
      - php
  php:
    image: php:8-fpm
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/www:/var/www
```

Advanced tab (Nginx config) :

```
root /var/www/html;

location / {
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```